# Laravel/PHP: How to Validate Rendered Fields?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have three forms, and one submit button. I only render two of the forms at any given point based on some predicate but when I submit the form, I would like the validate only the fields that exist in the currently rendered forms

Here is what the validation rules look

```
public function rules($request) {
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'firm' => 'required|max:255',
        'contactnumber' => 'required|numeric',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:'.Spark::minimumPasswordLength(),
        'vat_id' => 'nullable|max:50|vat_id',
        'terms' => 'required|accepted',
        'accountHolderEmail' => 'required|email|max:255',
        'accountHolder' => 'required|max:255',
        'cardNumber' => 'required|numeric|digits:16',
        'cvc' => 'required|numeric|digits:3',
        'expiry_month' => array('required', 'regex:/0[1-9]|1[0-2]/'),
        'expiry_year' => 'required|numeric|digits:4|date_format:Y|after:'. date('Y', strtotime('-1 years'))

    ];
}
```

I would like to validate the last six fields only when I have rendered the form that contains those fields, but I just cannot seem to get it right.

I have tried adding `sometimes` but that just makes the fields completely optional and that is not the desired behavior because when the form requiring those fields is rendered, we actually need the fields to be mandatory.

I have also tried using `Validator::make` and passing those last six fields there and that does not do it as well.

Comment: can you set a flag for forms? you can then set values for different flags and check if the value of those flags is a certain value and use `required_if:your_flag,your_value`

Comment: Do they all submit to the same endpoint?

Comment: Yes they all submit to same endpoint

Comment: @MehravishTemkar that worked. Please post as answer. Will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set flags for each form and set a value for them whether they are rendered or not.

For example

```
<input name="flag1" value="1"> //if form 1 is rendered
<input name="flag2" value="0"> //if form 2 is not rendered
```

Then you can use `required_if` validator like mentioned below:

```
'name' => 'required_if:flag1,1|max:255',
'firm' => 'required_if:flag2,1|max:255',
```